# SQL Change Tracking and Microsoft Sync Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, microsoft-sync-framework, change-tracking

I'm kind of new with databases and SQL and I'm struggling trying to understand how `SQL Change Tracking` and `Microsoft Sync Framework` work together.

I couldn't find some clear examples about how to sync databases with `Microsoft Sync Framework` but hopefully I found [this](https://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/part-3-synchronizing-tables-where-client-and-server-primary-keys-are-different/) site, modified the code and got syncing working on my two databases, here is the code I got:

```
    // Server connection
    using (SqlConnection serverConn = new SqlConnection(serverConnectionString))
    {
        if (serverConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            serverConn.Open();

        // Client connection
        using (SqlConnection clientConn = new SqlConnection(clientConnectionString))
        {
            if (clientConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                clientConn.Open();

            const string scopeName = "DifferentPKScope";

            // Provision Server
            var serverProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(serverConn);
            if (!serverProvision.ScopeExists(scopeName))
            {
                var serverScopeDesc = new DbSyncScopeDescription(scopeName);
                var serverTableDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable(table, serverConn);

                // Add the table to the descriptor
                serverScopeDesc.Tables.Add(serverTableDesc);

                serverProvision.PopulateFromScopeDescription(serverScopeDesc);
                serverProvision.Apply();
            }

            // Provision Client
            var clientProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(clientConn);
            if (!clientProvision.ScopeExists(scopeName))
            {
                var clientScopeDesc = new DbSyncScopeDescription(scopeName);
                var clientTableDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable(table, clientConn);

                // Add the table to the descriptor
                clientScopeDesc.Tables.Add(clientTableDesc);

                clientProvision.PopulateFromScopeDescription(clientScopeDesc);
                clientProvision.SetCreateTrackingTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.CreateOrUseExisting);
                clientProvision.Apply();
            }

            // Create the sync orchestrator
            var syncOrchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator();

            // Setup providers
            var localProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(scopeName, clientConn);
            var remoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(scopeName, serverConn);

            syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider = localProvider;
            syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider = remoteProvider;

            // Set the direction of sync session
            syncOrchestrator.Direction = direction;

            // Execute the synchronization process
            return syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();
        }
    }
```

So on this way any changes are synchronized between my two databases. But I wanted a way for my C# app to automatically synchronize both databases when something changes so I found something called `Change Tracking` [here](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2012/06/01/Database-Synchronization-with-the-Microsoft-Sync-Framework.aspx?Page=1). I downloaded the example code that provides a `SynchronizationHelper` that also creates tables in my databases called `"{TableName}_tracking"`. This is another table that tracks the changes and indeed it does, whenever I change something in my database the `_tracking` is updated with the elements I changed, added or removed. `Change Tracking` doesn't automatically synchronize my databases, it just keeps track of the changes in them, what's the purpose of this?

With the first code, synchronization works but no `_tracking` table is created, does it just synchronize everything in the table no matter what changed? If that's the case, for big databases I should be using `Change Tracking`?

Maybe this is something trivial but I have been googling and testing a lot of code but I can't find a clear answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install Sync Framework, it comes with a help file that includes several walkthroughs of synchronizing databases. the first link you referred to and the second uses the same sync provider and they both have tracking tables. Sync Framework supports using the built-in SQL Change Tracking feature or using a custom-one that Sync Framework creates by itself (the _tracking).

Sync Framework sits outside of your database and you need to invoke it in order to fire the synchronization. Change Tracking is what it says it is- tracking changes.

if you want your databases to do the sync, you might want to check SQL Replication instead.